# Errors installing rms package on R

Tags: r, package, rms

I'm having issues installing the rms package.

```
install.packages("rms",dependencies=TRUE)

also installing the dependencies ‘mvtnorm’, ‘multcomp’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
mvtnorm  1.0-11 1.0-12              TRUE
multcomp 1.4-11 1.4-12             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/rms_5.1-4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2059020 bytes (2.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/8d/f0mybfpd5wv97wgpv9m26dkm0000gn/T//Rtmp8cPKUt/downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘mvtnorm’, ‘multcomp’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165938 bytes (162 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 162 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/multcomp_1.4-12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 609805 bytes (595 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 595 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘multcomp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/multcomp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘multcomp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/8d/f0mybfpd5wv97wgpv9m26dkm0000gn/T/Rtmp8cPKUt/downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried a lot of suggestions for related problems I found on other blogs posts but nothing has worked! Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Ben

Comment: `gfortran: No such file or directory` is the key. I don't have macos, but perhaps https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ is relevant.

Comment: From past experience, I highly recommend using the version on the tools page linked above—trying to install other ways has mostly just been a waste of time for me. Or just say "no" and use a slightly older precompiled binary, which will probably be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly sure how, but playing around with this seemed to work!